# Console in C++ Cascade for blackberry

Tags: c++, cascade, blackberry-10

I want to use `console.log` in my application to print output in console window, but the compiler reports this error

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
'console' was not declared in this scope    CalcolatorQML.cpp   ‪/CalcolatorQML/src‬    line 27 C/C++ Problem
```

Now how can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a console windown on BB10. To log to the IDE console terminal you can use stdout/stderr (cout/cerr) but these should be removed prior to production. Output to stdout/stderr in production mode (with no debugger attached) ends up being stored on the device 'disk' taking up space and causing unneed wear on the flash devices.

For production error loggin you should use the slog2 facility either directly or by using the QDebug object.

Answer (score 1):

If console.log() in QML and qDebug<< in CPP are not printing messages in console the use the following method in your main.cpp class

```
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const char* msg){
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", msg);                
                fflush(stdout);
}
```

and the in main function use "qInstallMsgHandler(myMessageOutput);" like the following

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Application app(argc, argv);
    qInstallMsgHandler(myMessageOutput);

}
```